# Position Graphic @ Bottom-Right in a Block using Apache FOP

Tags: java, xsl-fo, saxon, apache-fop

Using Apache FOP I want to place an `<fo:external-graphic>` within an `<fo:block>` or a `<fo:block-container>` of a fixed size.  The Graphic should be positioned in the bottom right-hand corner of the block. I just can't figure out how to specify the position. Any ideas anyone?

Now if I only had one Image it would be no problem to figure out where to position it, but I have multiple Images of slightly different sizes & want them (after - proportional - scaling) to be justified Bottom-Right.

In my desperation I tried `<fo:external-graphic allowed-width-scale="150% 50% 25%"/>` which according to w3c is a valid option, but Saxon threw a `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException`.

And now, by popular demand, some FO:

```
<fo:block-container position="absolute" top="42mm" left="192mm" width="70mm" background-color="red">
    <fo:block background-color="green">
            <fo:external-graphic border-style="none" content-height="13mm" src="wiki_96dpi_290x81_7673x2143my.jpg" background-color="blue"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

The result is the following:

[image: The left-justified result]

Now, how do I get the Image right-justified within the `<fo:block-container>` so the green is on the left? Like this:

[image: Desired result, right-justified]

So, after applying Tonys solution, the result looked like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="sign_height">13mm</xsl:variable><!-- Höhe des Unterschrifts -->
    :             :
    :             :
<fo:block-container position="absolute" top="42mm" left="192mm" width="70mm">
    <fo:block text-align="right" max-height="{$sign_height}" font-size="0" background-color="green">
        <fo:external-graphic content-height="{$sign_height}" src="wiki_96dpi_290x81_7673x2143my.jpg" border-style="none"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Note how `max-height="..."` & `font-size="0"` on the `<fo:block>` also got rid of the (unwanted) Padding above & below the Image.

[image: The final result]

Comment: There is no XPath or XSLT code in there in your question, if you encounter a problem with an XSLT processor consider to post a minimal but complete sample allowing others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The fact that you're getting an exception from Saxon means you're doing something wrong at the XSLT level, this won't be anything to do with whether you're generating valid XSL-FO or not. You need to post details of the error you're getting and the XSLT code that's it's complaining about. Note: diagnosing a problem always starts from the error message, so posting a question that doesn't quote the error message isn't helpful.

Comment: Mike: I know XSLT is your main focus, but thought you might have touched on the FO stuff in passing & have some suggestion. I set up a Saxonica Account this morning with a view to posting the XSLT issue there in due course...

Comment: Martin: I didn't post any XSLT code because that's what I was hoping to get as the answer to the question. The question was stated quite clearly: I have an <fo:block-container> of fixed height & width.  Within that an <fo:block> which is required as a parent of the <fo:external-graphic> whos URI may select from a pool of Images of various size. The selected Image should be displayed bottom-right in the area defined by the <fo:block-container>, it's as simple as that, or rather, it should be.

Comment: Saxon throwing an exception means that you didn't get as far as running FOP. In the first graphic at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e147, Saxon does the 'XSLT Transform' part independently from FOP doing the 'XSL Formatter' part. If you roll back your desperate changes until you get something that neither Saxon nor FOP fall over on then post a minimal example of the XSLT and/or the generated XSL-FO plus a description of where it's going wrong, then we'll be better able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just align the graphic to the right, add `text-align="right"` to the `fo:block`.

---

To fit the `fo:block` to the graphic, also add `max-height="13mm" font-size="0"`.